# Timer run in CGridview Column - Yii Framework

Tags: javascript, yii, timer, cgridview

I'm trying to run timer dynamically for CGridView Column data, the following is the calculation to be done to run the timer,

`session_duration + (now - session_start)` - This value should be run dynamically in hhmmss format lively in Cgridview column,

[image]

Please can anyone help me to proceed this.

Comment: Value = current_time - session_start format hhmmss

Comment: how to run timer by starting current_time - session_start ?

Comment: Please paste the HTML code in JSfiddle.

Comment: what have you tryed so far?

Comment: I have no idea to invoke javascript for cgridview column. Can anyone advise me to proceed this ?